# Cust Interface to post in blog in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have create our own widget on wordpress dashboard to post but Now I want to list category box like Posting by Inbuilt Interface of Wordpress but Can not. Please check following picture 
[image]

I want to add categories like following
[image]

Please let me know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

1. [Inspect](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) the regular WP widget and find an unique identifier.
2. Open WP core files in your favorite [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).
3. Do a global search for the identifier.
4. After locating the widget, copy all the code to your own widget and adapt as necessary.